# Listview row colour with no subitems not changing colour correctly

Tags: c#

I'm using a `listView` as a log and adding text to it, what i'm trying to do is colour a line green if it's a success or red if it's a failure, the problem is the way i have it now is it will change all the text in the listView the target colour instead of just the row, i'm not using any subitem rows, just:

```
line
line
line
etc
```

**The code for that part is:**

```
            Log.RecordAdded += record => Invoke(() =>
            {
                if (record.Contains("failed"))
                {
                    listViewLog.Items.Add(record);
                    listViewLog.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
                }
                else if (record.Contains("success"))
                {
                    listViewLog.Items.Add(record);
                    listViewLog.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
                }
                else 
                {
                    listViewLog.Items.Add(record);
                }
            });

        public static class Log
        {
            public static event Action<string> RecordAdded;
            private static void OnRecordAdded(string record)
            {
                Action<string> tmp = RecordAdded;
                tmp?.Invoke(record);
         }

         public static void Add(string record)
         {
            OnRecordAdded($"[{DateTime.Now}] {record}");
         }
```

I never wrote the `Log` class it was someone else, I just used it for quickness, I don't see any obvious issues, to add to it i would just use `Log.Add("This was a success!")` but all text would change to green in this case.

Can anyone see anything i have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you would need a different overload of the `Add` method. [This one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.add?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_ListView_ListViewItemCollection_Add_System_Windows_Forms_ListViewItem_) because it:

> Adds an existing ListViewItem to the collection.

A closer look at the [ListViewItem documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem?view=net-5.0) shows that it has also a [ForeColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.forecolor?view=net-5.0) property.

instead of adding simply strings to `listViewLog.Items.Add(record);` create first a `ListViewItem` change the color and add the item